How to use didSelectItemAt method with using UICollectionView?
I have a  UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. And I want to change label on cell click.
I use this code to do it:
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MediumTableCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MediumTableCell    
    cell.title.text = "true"
}

But it is doesn't work. How to fix it?
Full code:
Cell code:
import UIKit

class MediumTableCell: UICollectionViewCell, SelfConfiguringCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "MediumTableCell"

    let title = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        title.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        title.textColor = .label
        contentView.addSubview(title)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func configure(with app: App) {
        title.text = app.name
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Just… no")
    }
}

Controller code:
class AppsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    let sections = Bundle.main.decode([Section].self, from: "appstore.json")
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, App>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createCompositionalLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        collectionView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: SectionHeader.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(FeaturedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: FeaturedCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(MediumTableCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MediumTableCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(SmallTableCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SmallTableCell.reuseIdentifier)

        createDataSource()
        reloadData()
    }

    func configure<T: SelfConfiguringCell>(_ cellType: T.Type, with app: App, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellType.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue \(cellType)")
        }

        cell.configure(with: app)
        return cell
    }

    func createDataSource() {
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, App>(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, app in
            switch self.sections[indexPath.section].type {
            case "mediumTable":
                return self.configure(MediumTableCell.self, with: app, for: indexPath)
            case "smallTable":
                return self.configure(SmallTableCell.self, with: app, for: indexPath)
            default:
                return self.configure(FeaturedCell.self, with: app, for: indexPath)
            }
        }

        dataSource?.supplementaryViewProvider = { [weak self] collectionView, kind, indexPath in
            guard let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: SectionHeader.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader else {
                return nil
            }

            guard let firstApp = self?.dataSource?.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else { return nil }
            guard let section = self?.dataSource?.snapshot().sectionIdentifier(containingItem: firstApp) else { return nil }
            if section.title.isEmpty { return nil }

            sectionHeader.title.text = section.title
            sectionHeader.subtitle.text = section.subtitle
            return sectionHeader
        }
    }

    func reloadData() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, App>()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)

        for section in sections {
            snapshot.appendItems(section.items, toSection: section)
        }

        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MediumTableCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MediumTableCell
        cell.title.text = "true"
    }

    func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let section = self.sections[sectionIndex]

            switch section.type {
            case "mediumTable":
                return self.createMediumTableSection(using: section)
            case "smallTable":
                return self.createSmallTableSection(using: section)
            default:
                return self.createFeaturedSection(using: section)
            }
        }

        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.interSectionSpacing = 20
        layout.configuration = config
        return layout
    }

    func createFeaturedSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))

        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        layoutItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5)

        let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.93), heightDimension: .estimated(350))
        let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])

        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        return layoutSection
    }

    func createMediumTableSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.33))

        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        layoutItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5)

        let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.93), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.55))
        let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])

        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered

        let layoutSectionHeader = createSectionHeader()
        layoutSection.boundarySupplementaryItems = [layoutSectionHeader]

        return layoutSection
    }

    func createSmallTableSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.2))
        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        layoutItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)

        let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.93), heightDimension: .estimated(200))
        let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])

        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        let layoutSectionHeader = createSectionHeader()
        layoutSection.boundarySupplementaryItems = [layoutSectionHeader]

        return layoutSection
    }

    func createSectionHeader() -> NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem {
        let layoutSectionHeaderSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.93), heightDimension: .estimated(80))
        let layoutSectionHeader = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: layoutSectionHeaderSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)
        return layoutSectionHeader
    }
}


Have you reload()? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata

@LawrenceGimenez add collectionView.reloadData() in didSelectItemAt nothing changes

cell.title.text = "true" <- You can't do this though.

Cells are reused, so you need to do 2 things:

Change the current data source and apply a new snapshot.
Also change the underlying data to prevent inconsistency when removing/inserting, etc, and you need to reload the entire data.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let selectedData = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else { return }

    //1. Update new snapshot    
    var updatedData = selectedData
    updatedData.name = "true"

    var newSnapShot = dataSource.snapshot()
    newSnapShot.insertItems([updatedData], beforeItem: selectedData)
    newSnapShot.deleteItems([selectedData])
    dataSource.apply(newSnapShot)


    //2. Update the underlying data
    //i.e, YourController/ViewModel had a list of `App`
    apps[indexPath.row].name = "true"
}


You don't need to dequeue the cell that is already created for the didSelectItemAt method. Instead you get it from the collection view by  supplying the indexPath to the cellForItem method. See the following code snippet:
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAt(at: indexPath) as! MediumTableCell {    
        cell.title.text = "true"
    }
}


That will appear to work, but your code has a problem: You don't change the underlying model data, so if you scroll the collection view and then scroll it back, or do anything else that causes that cell to be reloaded, the change will be lost. You need to change the model data that holds the title for the cell at that index path.

@DuncanC Yes. I have this problem

@DuncanC thank you for the info. Well I just answered to what the OP asked: I want to change label on cell click. But it is doesn't work. How to fix it?. I thought the OP could able to handle the data update. But it looks like he/she does not.

Yes, need to update underlying data model and then reload data

@Kozmotronik Will you update the underlying data model and then reload the data? So I can accept the answer. Or won't you update the answer? Yes, I asked: I want to change label on cell click. But it doesn't work. How to fix it?. A full answer with more information would be more helpful in this case

Well I would, but there is already a complete answer by @sonle. You can accept that answer if it works for ya. Let me know if it does not and I update my answer then.
